# If it possible to access AdminConfig in the Liberty Profile (non ND)

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, websphere-portal, wsadmin

Is it possible to access AdminConfig.getid inside the WebSphere Liberty Profile (non ND), just pure Liberty profile, or even Base version?

Any particular jars needed?

Comment: Are you trying to access configuration for Liberty using AdminConfig.getid or are you trying to access traditional configuration from an application in Liberty?

Comment: I have got Liberty and Base without wsadmin.sh, and I am wondering if there is any other way, than manual edit of the server.xml etc, to administer the deployments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AdminConfig` object is related to the `wsadmin` tool. According to [IBM Documentation for wsadmin](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_scriptingep.html), it cannot be used with the Liberty profile. The `wsadmin` tool should be available with a full profile created under the Base version.

You can refer to [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/welc6topscripting.html) for more information on using `wsadmin`. You can use the Java Management Extensions (JMX) framework to make use of the `wsadmin` objects using Java MBeans. Alternatively, you can use the Administration Thin Client to write your own standalone program to remotely connect to and manage WebSphere Application Servers.

Comment: But the Base version is not a Full Profile, or am I wrong? From what I know Base is a separate product just like the Liberty

Comment: WAS is designed for compliance to the Java EE specification. However, a lot of web applications only require compliance with the Java EE Web Profile specification, which is a subset of the full Java EE spec. A 'full profile' provides compliance to the full Java EE spec. A 'liberty profile' provides compliance to only the Web Profile spec.

Comment: The 'Base' edition of WAS can create both full profiles and liberty profiles. The 'Liberty' edition of WAS can only create Liberty profiles. Hope that clears up the confusion.

Comment: yup. So I am talking about Liberty full profile (not core). Still, it doesnt contain the wsadmin? If not then what's the difference between Liberty Core and Libery run on Full profile?

Comment: Licensing cost, basically. Liberty Core can only create Liberty profiles, so it costs much less than the Base Edition. In comparison, you need the Base, Express or ND edition to create full profiles, which costs more. If you already have a license to the Base, Express or ND edition, you are free to create Liberty profiles. I think you have to install it separately, though.

Comment: but still liberty profile would be exactly the same but will inherit classes that came with the Base, Express or ND edition. But liberty binaries are still the same

Comment: Please refer to the IBM Redbook [here](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/Redbooks.nsf/RedpieceAbstracts/sg248022.html?Open). Section 1.3.3 - Profile Capability Comparison.

Comment: that's all about the licences. but still liberty profile would be exactly the same but will inherit classes that came with the Base, Express or ND edition. Are the liberty binaries still the same for each edition?

Comment: Java classes implemented by Liberty are listed [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_feat.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5). The binaries _should_ be the same for all editions because the programming model has to remain consistent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115490/discussion-between-xsurgent-and-meso-2600).